# How to use command line interface for a program

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm trying to figure out how to run a program from command line. There's this particular program I'm working on that has command line interface, [BroadcastByPhone](http://voicent.com/auto-dialer-developer.php)

There's not a clear instruction on the page where to type the command, it only says `vcast.exe "C:\mygroup\list.voc" -startnow -wavfile "C:\mygroup\hello.wav"` this following line will launch Voicent BroadcastByPhone program and start broadcasting

I'm using Windows 7, how can I invoke the program using command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Start Menu, search for Command Prompt (pretty sure that's what its called), and then paste that in. Then hit enter and it should run in the Command Prompt Window.

Comment: it says 'vcast.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You probably have to give it the path to where the vcast.exe file is